Firebase Auth Exception not caught by catch
When signing in with wrong credentials an Exception is thrown as expected. However, the catch block fails to catch the Exception resulting in a crash.

Exception has occurred. FirebaseAuthException
([firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is
incorrect, malformed or has expired.)

void signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
  state = state.copyWith(isLoading: true);
  try {
    UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.trim(), password: password.trim());
    state = state.copyWith(user: await _createMyUserFromFirebaseUser(result.user!), isLoading: false);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    state = state.copyWith(isLoading: false, error: e.toString());
  } on PlatformException catch (_) {} catch (_) {}
}

I have found other mentions of this issue but never a solution to it. As you can see I have tried specifying the Exception to catch, but it somehow is never caught.

I created an example to show what might be going on:
typedef State = ({String userName, bool isLoading, String error});

State state = (userName: 'not set', isLoading: true, error: 'nothing');

void signInWithEmail({
  required String email,
  required String password,
  Function? errorCallback,
}) async {
  if (errorCallback == null) {
    final userName = await Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => 'Nick2001');
    state = (userName: userName, isLoading: false, error: 'nothing');
  } else {
    throw errorCallback();
  }
}

void main() async {
  try {
    signInWithEmail(
      email: 'a@b.com',
      password: '1234',
      errorCallback: () => 'User not registered.',
    );
    print(state);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Caught error in main:');
    print('  $e');
  }
}

This program produces the following console output, even though the catch block is set up to catch every possible exception.
$ dart main.dart
State: (error: nothing, isLoading: true, userName: not set)
Unhandled exception:
Exception: User not registered.
#0      signInWithEmail (file:///work/main.dart:14:5)
#1      main (file:///work/main.dart:20:5)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#3      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)


Now we change the signature of the function signInWithEmail to return a Future<void> and await the function in main:
Future<void> signInWithEmail({
  required String email,
  required String password,
  Function? errorCallback,
}) async {
  if (errorCallback == null) {
    final userName = await Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => 'Nick2001');
    state = (userName: userName, isLoading: false, error: 'nothing');
  } else {
    throw errorCallback();
  }
}

void main() async {
  try {
    await signInWithEmail(
      email: 'a@b.com',
      password: '1234',
      errorCallback: () => Exception('User not registered.'),
    );
    print('State: $state');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Caught error in main:');
    print('  $e');
  }
}

Running this program produces the expected output:
Caught error in main:
  Exception: User not registered.

For a detailed explanation see Handling errors in void Dart function marked async.
In a nutshell: An error thrown in a function marked async is a future error. If this function is not awaited in the try-catch block the future error is thrown after the completion of the synchronously executed try-catch block and is therefore not caught.

Thank you! I will implement this and will get back to you on whether it solved the problem for me!
I do have a follow up question, though. How would I now catch specific FirebaseAuth Expections? As far as I understand your answer, a normal Exception with the message 'User not registered.' is thrown whenever something goes wrong with the Sign-In. Or is the main thing really that the signInWithEmail is awaited for in the main and as long as I do that I could have a normal error handling process within the signInWithEmail?

The main thing is that the async function is awaited for. In your case, I noticed that  signInWithEmail returns void.  In that case, the Dart analyser does not warn about any unwaited future, making it easier to forget to await the function.

Could the exception be thrown in _createMyUserFromFirebaseUser?

I have managed to solve the problem with your help! I made the function a Future, am awaiting it, and have added a callback which is called whenever the log-in is successful. Thank you!

I have only now seen your second comment. I mean theoretically it could I'm sure, but it is only called if there was not exception in the Firebase Sign-In and all I am doing in the method is creating a custom user from the information in the Firebase User. So rather unlikely I think.
